# Unable to refund on Magento 2.1.4

Tags: refund, magento-2.1.4

We used to refund for orders through "Invoice" then "Credit Memo" all the time on Magento. However, the option stopped working and whenever we try to refund, it shows that there has been an error and the refund cannot be processed.

We use Authorize.net as our payment and we haven't changed anything on Magento nor Authorize.net that could've caused this problem.

I'm currently refunding through Authorize.net manually but since it does not leave anything on Magento that the refund has taken place, it's causing all sorts of data problem.

Did anyone go through the same problem and was able to find out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net Refund requires one day time .Meaning if customer has ordered something today and wants refund then admin should refund it the next day i.e. tomorrow . If your try to refund on same day then it gives you some gateway error.

Comment: I understand about their one day after policy and have tried after 1 business day but still does not work.